# How to get array values using foreach in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel and php. I have this code in one of my controllers:

```
$group_by_precedence = array("true", "false");
```

And this code in the view:

```html
@foreach ($group_by_precedence as $value)
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8">
                <a class="collapse-button collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    href="#collapse_&&&&&"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapse_&&&&&"
                    onclick="loadDealsFor(&&&&&, 'precedence');"
                    style="width: 100%; display: block; margin: -10px; padding: 10px;"
                >
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i> <i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i> exists
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
@endforeach
```

I tried but I did not manage to duplicate the code twice, and replace the `&&&&&` with the values from the `$group_by_precedence` array; first `true` and then `false`.

Currently the bad solution is to duplicate the code in the view, and just change the `&&&&&` with `true` and `false`.

Comment: you want to duplicate thead ?

Comment: Use `{{ $value }}` in place of `&&&&&&`. More on [Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#loops)

Comment: As @brombeer already shared the documentation, I will just add that it is very important that you read the Framework documentation, you are no magician, so you cannot know what the frameworks offers and can do, so read it fully and then you will be able to mostly do anything you want, and if you have any doubts or questions, you can come back with new questions, but please read the documentation so you don't waste time and learn how to use it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it might help:

```html
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($group_by_precedence as $value)
            <th colspan="8">
                <a class="collapse-button collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    href="#collapse_{{ $value }}"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapse_{{ $value }}"
                    onclick="loadDealsFor({{ $value }}, 'precedence');"
                    style="width: 100%; display: block; margin: -10px; padding: 10px;"
                >
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i> <i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i> exists
                </a>
            </th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blade file you can print the vars with `{{ $var }}` . like that:

```php
$group_by_precedence = array("true", "false");

@foreach ($group_by_precedence as $value)
    <p>Your value is: {{ $value }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Tnx it is solved

```
@foreach ($group_by_precedence as $value)                   
                   
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              
                                <th colspan="8">
                                    <a class="collapse-button collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_{{ $value }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_{{ $value }}" onclick = "loadDealsFor('{{ $value }}', 'precedence');"  style="width: 100%;display: block;margin: -10px;padding: 10px;">
                                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-plus"></i> <i class="zmdi zmdi-minus"></i>exists
                                    </a>
                                </th>
                                   
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="collapse_{{ $value }}" class="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-loading="no">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="8" id="collapse_{{ $value }}_loader" class="force-white"></td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
                    @endforeach
```

code is ok but dont u think this will create wrong id because u placed the whole object $value rather than accesing through id like `{{ $value->id}}`